# Sort and delete last container

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Have possible often deleting from the last in the sequence, still there are looped sort involved, so the question would be is it relevant in meaning of speed on a < Kb sized container **to use vector** (instead other available containers and algorithms) and use it as is on:

```
std::vector<int> elements;
bool single_element = false

while (!single_element)
{
    ApplySomeAlgorithm(elements, params); //weighted, but simple and comparable with looped deleting bellow  
    std::sort (elements.begin(), elements.end(), sort_function); // simple sort on int
    single_element = (int (elements.size()) > 1) ? false : true;

    while (!single_element)
    {
        if !(ApplySomeAlgorithm1(elements.back())) // actually only getter
            break;
        else
            elements.pop_back();
        single_element = (int (elements.size()) > 1) ? false : true;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hi kradem. Your text is a bit difficult to understand, but here is my answer on what I guess what your question might be: If your data structure is used in the three stages (1) filling, (2) sorting, and (3) removing one-by-one from the back, then using a vector should be fine in terms of efficiency, provided that stage (1) is not too inefficient. Note that you have a double-nested while loop with the same looping condition, so you could replace the first "while" with an "if" without changing the behaviour of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, was helpfull. This is simplified version, but both whiles need same single_element, ifn first call to method elements are reference in this example (or I meant to be)